# NSIS - I want to uninstall A LOT of files

Tags: nsis

In simple programs which contain, for example, an exe and a Winamp plugin, we can simply create directories and extract files to them, right? But imagine an app where we have 1000+ files. How to easily write an installer-uninstaller NSI script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If most of the files are in subdirectories you can use something like `File /r somedir` and `RMDir /r "$InstDir\somedir"` but this would also delete other files if the user stored something there for whatever reason.

Try [these helper macros](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Uninstall_only_installed_files) if you only want to uninstall the files you install.

You can also use `!system` to call out to a custom batch-file/script that generates the list of files and writes them to a .nsh you can `!include`.

Comment: `File /r somedir` was really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Be *extremely* careful with this.
Remember that the user might choose to install your program in "C:\"